# Weld has ambiguous dependencies error only in production

Tags: java

I build a application with weld se 2.0 and other simple dependencies. 
In my development environment(eclipse) this works fine, no errors, but... in production the app crash totally and the part of intern dependencies of weld throws 'Ambiguous dependencies' errors:

```
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318 Cannot resolve an ambiguous     dependency between:
  - Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.weld.injection.EmptyInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl$InstanceInjectionPoint] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
        at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.resolve(BeanManagerImpl.java:1176)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validatePseudoScopedInjectionPoint(Validator.java:929)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.reallyValidatePseudoScopedBean(Validator.java:902)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validatePseudoScopedInjectionPoint(Validator.java:935)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.reallyValidatePseudoScopedBean(Validator.java:902)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validatePseudoScopedBean(Validator.java:879)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:192)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:209)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:521)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:71)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:69)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

....

```
 Exception 0 :
 org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [Instance<Object>] 
with qualifiers [@Any] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @Any      org.jboss.weld.environment.se.beans.InstanceManager.instances]. 
Possible dependencies:
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.weld.Weld] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Implicit Bean [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance] with qualifiers [@Default],
  - Managed Bean [class org.jboss.weld.servlet.StaticWeldProvider$EnhancedWeld] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:408)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:327)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:178)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:209)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:521)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:71)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:69)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

....

```
 Exception 0 :
 org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [List<String>] with qualifiers [@Parameters] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @GlobalProperties @ApplicationScoped public br.com.aptalaser.mensageria.factory.PropertiesConfigurationBuilder.getProperties(@Parameters List<String>)].
Possible dependencies:
  - Producer Method [List<String>] with qualifiers [@Parameters @Any] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Parameters public org.jboss.weld.environment.se.beans.ParametersFactory.getArgs()],
  - Producer Method [List<String>] with qualifiers [@Parameters @Any] declared as [[UnbackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces @Parameters public org.jboss.weld.environment.se.beans.ParametersFactory.getArgs()]
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:408)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:327)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:178)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:209)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:521)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:71)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:69)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I use jdk 1.7 and weld-se 2.0.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>apta</groupId>
<artifactId>mensageria</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-weld-se-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.22</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>
        <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5-pre1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld.se</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-se-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.14.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>org.jboss.weld.environment.se.StartMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

What can be the cause? My app works fine in eclipse, my dependencies is bad configured or my build process is wrong? What i can do to avoid this exception?

Kind regards Samuel.

Answer (score 1):

well, this is a problem of attention i have to admit it, the solution is put it in your beans.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
   version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all">
    <scan>
        <exclude name="org.jboss.weld.**" />
    </scan>
</beans>
```

as the follow in: http://weld.cdi-spec.org/documentation,

sorry guys.